# c# how to use get; to return a value if the value was not set?

Tags: c#

I am trying to define `get; set;` value when initializing an attribute.

I have the following interface

```
public interface IReportColumn
{
    string Title { get; set; }

    string ColumnKey { get; }

    AggregateFunctions AggregateFunction { get; set; }

    string SqlAlias { get;  }

}
```

What I need to do is set the attribute `SqlAlias` to a random string if `AggregateFunction == AggregateFunctions.None || ColumnKey == null`. But, since I am generating a random string here, I don't want it to change ever time I call the get method. I want to be able to get it, set it and reuse the same value through the entire request.

This is how I am implementing my interface

```
public class ReportColumnMsSqlServer : IReportColumn
{

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string ColumnKey { get; set; }

    public AggregateFunctions AggregateFunction { get; set; }

    public string SqlAlias {

        get {

           return this.GetColumnName();

        } 
    }


    private string GetColumnName()
    {
        string columName = this.ColumnKey;

        if (columName == null || this.AggregateFunction != AggregateFunctions.None)
        {
            columName = Convert.ToBase64String(Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray());
        }

        return string.Format("{0}", new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9]").Replace(columName, string.Empty));
    }

}
```

How can I set the SqlAlias value only once based on my condition above and keep the same value through the entire request?

Comment: Create a local field. if null, generate id else return saved id

Comment: Since your question is about *setting* a property value, why are you asking about *get*? Use a private setter and set the value in the constructor

Comment: A property getter that mutates another property just seems wrong to me.

Comment: I may dont get the question - but why dont you use a readonly property?
what do you mean under "entire request" ? web request? etc.. ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can introduce a new private field to store the information, and only calculate the value the first time it's accessed:

```
private string _sqlAlias = null;
public string SqlAlias {

    get {
       if (_sqlAlias == null)
           _sqlAlias = this.GetColumnName();
       return _sqlAlias;

    } 
}
```

Depending on your use case, since the return value is based on both the `ColumnKey` and the `AggregateFunction`, you could implement the setters of both of those properties to set `_sqlAlias` back to `null`, so further calls to `SqlAlias` will recalculate the new value, based on the other updated properties.

Comment: Can't I reuse the same variable like so `        public string SqlAlias 
        {
            get 
            {
                if (SqlAlias == null)
                {
                    return this.GetColumnName();   
                }

                return this.SqlAlias;
                         
            } 
        }`?  I have two way to set the variable and only one once it is random

Comment: @Jaylen No, reading `SqlAlias` within the getter of itself will cause a stack overflow exception.

Comment: @Jaylen if you do that you'll be creating a circular reference. `{get { if (SqlAlias` (calls get again)....

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple "lazy loading" pattern.

```
private string _sqlAlias;
public string SqlAlias {
     get {
         if (_sqlAlias == null) {
             _sqlAlias = GetColumnName();
         }

         return _sqlAlias;
     }
}
```